# Acceptable microservice-microservice communication time/latency?

Tags: hibernate, cloud, microservices

How long is the maximum acceptable time for the communication between two microservices? my microservices A and B perform

GET from client -> A -> B -> A -> Response to client

and it takes about 820ms. Is it too high? How can I reduce the processing time inside a microservice? I use spring and hibernate inside microservices

Comment: Only your clients can answer what the acceptable time limit is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no maximum acceptance time, it really depends on your case what exactly this request does.

But, from my experience, If your services do some CRUD operations with entities and some regular business logic, then 820ms is too much. You should, probably, find the bottleneck, usually its IO operation, like Database queries.

I would say If some request communication takes more than 200-300 ms than this a good point to look inside and investigate where the is the bottleneck.

Comment: To check what causes the problem, I created a simple route that returns a string. and even that route takes 490ms! What could be the solution?

Comment: Yah, probably something is wrong. It's hard to say, where is a problem, since as I said it really depends, and there may be a lot of things that may have an impact on performance. What kind of framework you are using, is that Spring? How your services communicated, via HTTP API? What about the network between the two services?

Comment: I'm using Spring. And I found what causes the latency. It is the load balancing in cloud gateway.

          uri: lb://job-service

This line causes the delay. if I replace the uri value with localhost address, the request goes through much quicker. Is there any way to mention job-service without lb prefix by the way?

Comment: Great job! I'm sure that I can help you `lb` prefix, maybe post it a separate question?

Comment: sure the link will be posted as a comment here. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144845/specifying-route-uri-in-spring-cloud-gateway-configuration