# Specifying route URI in Spring Cloud Gateway Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Here is the yml for spring cloud gateway. I want to write URI without load balancing. But as I'm using Eureka, I don't think hardcoding something like "localhost:6678" is a good idea. I would like to specify the service name, without the lb prefix. Any way to write it ?

```
  spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: before_route
        uri: lb://hello-service
```

I'm seeing this on the console when I run the gateway:

```
You already have RibbonLoadBalancerClient on your classpath. It will be used by default. As Spring Cloud Ribbon is in maintenance mode. We recommend switching to BlockingLoadBalancerClient instead. In order to use it, set the value of `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false` or remove spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon from your project.
```

What is the official alternative of Ribbon? How can I enable it in my project instead of Ribbon?

Edit: I'm trying to avoid load balancing for now because of poor performance. Without lb I'm getting my request served within 150ms whereas lb makes it 500ms+

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ribbon will be supported until mid 2021. You can use a static server list if you don't want eureka but still use `lb://...`. Spring Cloud Loadbalancer is the replacement see this presentation for more details. https://www.infoq.com/presentations/netflix-spring-cloud/

Comment: If i use a static server list, the request gets processed in 150ms. lb causes 500+ ms. That's why im confused whether i should add lb

Comment: is it consistently slower or just the first request? That's wasn't in your original question.

Comment: That's consistently slower. Without lb - 150ms. With lb- 500ms

Comment: You're right. I should've added it to the question. Edits done!

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: aipgateway
```

Comment: While this configuration may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* it answers the question improves its long-term value.